# CSS3 image hover transaction outer of div

Tags: html, css

i add CSS3 transaction effect for image hover like this :

CSS:

```
.list-news{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
.list-news:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(13px) scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(13px) scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(13px) scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(13px) scale(1.1);
    transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(13px) scale(1.1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="list-news bg-blue-shadow">
        <article>
            <header>
                <figure>
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://wedesignthemes.com/html/kidslife/images/image5.jpg">
                    <figcaption class="bg-yellow">
                            <h3>Title</h3>

                        <p>Description</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

This worked but in hover image is over/outer of `div`. how do fix this?!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wbfgm0ye/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean that the image should only zoom in but keep size, so just add an image container with

```
overflow:hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wbfgm0ye/1/

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you applied the :hover to `.list-news`, which means that the img's transition effect is applied when `.list-news` is hovered. Change it to `.list-news img:hover { ... }` and it should work.